# Angular js - Cannot read property error - using reference datatype

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am using angular js in which I have a Class Object and Student Object.

```
var Class= new Schema(
{
name :String
section :String,
strength : Number,
teacher : String,
student : {
            personal : {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Student'
            }
            markTotal : Number,
            rank : Number

        }
}
);

var Student= new Schema(
{
name: String,
age : String
}
);
```

---

In my jade file,

```
window.class='!{JSON.stringify(class)}';
```

If I reference

class.student.personal.name ==> it is erroring out saying Cannot read property 'name'

Error :

```
TypeError: D:\Branching\app\views\class\home.jade:4
    2| block content
    3|  script(type="text/javascript").
  **> 4|        window.class='!{$eval(class)}'**        
    5|  div(ng-controller="controllers.class.home.main as main")
    6|      .masterhead.segment
    7|          .ui.page.grid.stackable

undefined is not a function
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here... what is `Schema`?

Comment: Schema is a keyword. Its used to create new object type.

Answer (score 0):

scope.$eval might be helpful to parse the student and schema instead of JSON.stringify,

```
window.class='!{scope.$eval(class)}';
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval

Comment: Cannot call method '$eval' of undefined - is the error I get

Comment: If window.class='!{scope.$eval(class)}'; is being assigned on the view then you should only need to call `window.class='!{$eval(class)}';` without scope.  Scope is only needed in controllers/directives/etc...

Comment: i have edited my original post with the new error. pls let me knw the solution for this .